# ASP.NET: CSV file is served, bypassing the web.config permission denial

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC website. There is a "**booklist.csv**" file in the "**~/booklist**" folder, which is not supposed to be served to the public.

To prevent the public from downloading this file using

```
www.mywebsite.com/booklist/booklist.csv
```

I have the following **web.config** file in the "**~/booklist**" folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have also the following in the root **web.config**:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

On our test server, it works, and public cannot download that "**booklist.csv**" file. But on our production server, it doesn't work. Public can still directly download that CSV file.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out. The production server was actually behaving as expected, the same as the testing server. It was my browser caching that CSV file. So my settings were correct.